# config.gem requires gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a bunch of config.gem statements in my environment.rb file:

```
config.gem "fastercsv", :version => "~>1.5.0"
  config.gem "parseexcel", :version => "~>0.5.2"
  config.gem "geokit", :version => "~>1.4.1"
  config.gem "facebooker", :version => "~>1.0.50"
```

...

If I do "rake gems:install" then I get this issue:
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- fastercsv

Well...i know there is no such file to load because I am trying to install it.  I suspect this may result from the location of my require.  I have a module in my lib directory:

```
module SmartContactsImporter

  require 'fastercsv'
  require 'parseexcel'
...
```

Maybe Rails doesn't like me requiring a gem there but it seems silly since there is nothing wrong with having your module depend on a gem.  Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**
Turns out that this issue also occured with mechanize, geokit, and the list is continuing.  It's a bit strange that config.gem doesn't work pretty easily out of the box.  FYI I'm not freezing my gems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave out the require in `SmartContactsImporter` this should work (`config.gem "fastercsv"` will do the require for you).

You can work around it when a `require` is needed in `environment.rb` with a:

```
begin
  require "rack/cache"
rescue LoadError
  STDERR.puts "not loaded rack/cache: #{$!}"
end
```

This is ugly but it does do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't require inside your module, config.gem will require it for you.

There's also a related issue with config.gem where it will attempt to require a dependent gem that is not yet installed whilst installing the gems, but this doesn't appear to be the case yet.